# Como abrir dos archivos binarios en C++

Tags: c++, archivo, dev-c++, binario

Tengo un problema quería abrir 2 archivos binarios a la vez pero me da un pequeño error se me repite el último y no se como solucionarlo llevo horas y horas pensando me gustaría saber el por que se repite en un archivo guardado "Lista" y en otro archivo guardo "Sub_Lista"

PD: el archivo lo escribe bien ya que si ponía `Archivo2.seekg(96, ios::cur)` se muestra el elemento que debería ir donde esta el elemento repetido.

Estructuras ocupadas

```
struct Sub_Lista{
    int sct;
    char nivel[30];
    char tel[30];
    char naturaleza[30];
};

struct Lista{
    char Dato[30];
    int cantidad;
};
```

Funcion que da error

```
void Lectura_archivo(){
    system("cls");
    int vueltas=0,i = 0,Pos;
    string Nombre;
    ifstream Archivo; // Archivo binario de entrada
    ifstream Archivo2;

    Lista elemento;
    Sub_Lista sub_elemento;

    Archivo.open("Elemento.txt", ios::binary);
    Archivo2.open("Sub_elementos.txt", ios::binary);


    Archivo.read((char *)(&elemento),sizeof(Lista));

    while (!Archivo.eof()){
        cout << "Asignatura: " << elemento.Dato << endl;
        cout << "Cantidad de elementos: " << elemento.cantidad << endl;
        Archivo2.read((char *)(&sub_elemento),sizeof(Sub_Lista));
        i = 0;
        // aca intenté abrirlo por partes pero no funcionó 
        // lo dejo por que tal vez sirva y no lo este ocupando bien
        // pos = vueltas*96
        //Archivo2.seekg(Pos, ios::cur);
        while (i < elemento.cantidad ){ // 96 x TDA
            cout << "Nivel: " << sub_elemento.nivel << endl;
            cout << "TEL: " << sub_elemento.tel << endl;
            cout << "SCT: " << sub_elemento.sct << endl;
            cout << "Naturaleza: " << sub_elemento.naturaleza << endl;
            cout << endl;
            i++;
            //vueltas ++;
            Archivo2.read((char *)(&sub_elemento),sizeof(Sub_Lista));
        }
        Archivo.read((char *)(&elemento),sizeof(Lista));
    }

    Archivo.close();
    Archivo2.close();   
}
```

Dejo la imagen como referencia

[image: En la imagen se puede ver que al 2do bucle los elementos se repiten]

Comment: Has probado a depurar tu programa paso a paso? Te habría ahorrado muchas horas de prueba y error...

Comment: realmente no lo hice bueno es por que no se como hacerlo buscare videos o pdf sobre eso muchas gracias

Comment: El IDE que utilizas, dev-c++ y todos los demás, incluyen la opción de depurar tu código. Pones puntos de parada en los puntos del código donde quieres que se pare, y ejecutas el programa en depuración. Cuando llega al punto de parada, se para y puedes comprobar el valor de todas las variables, e ir ejecutando instrucción por instrucción el resto del código viendo como cambian las variables. Completamente indispensable para programar. Te recomiendo que lo utilices.

Comment: Muchas gracias lo intentaré

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El comprobar por [EOF](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/EOF) es un error habitual en la lectura de flujos de dato a archivo. La [bandera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_flag) EOF se establece **después** de leer, no antes…

Por ello una vez leído el último dato la bandera EOF aún no se ha levantado y la condición `!Archivo.eof()` es verdadera, por lo tanto se intenta leer otro registro que al no existir deja los datos como estaban, dando la errónea sensación de que se ha leído dos veces lo mismo. Lo ilustro con un poco de [arte ASCII](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arte_ASCII):

```
Leyenda
-------
Punto de lectura: ^
Registro:         [x]
```

Al principio, el punto de lectura está al inicio del primer dato.

```
Dato: ?
[0][1][2][3]EOF
^
```

Al leer un dato, avanzamos el punto de lectura el tamaño del dato, dejando el punto de lectura al **inicio** del siguiente dato:

```
Dato: 0
[0][1][2][3]EOF
   ^
```

Cuando leemos el último registro, el puntero de lectura está al final del archivo, pero **aún no ha leído EOF**:

```
Dato: 3
[0][1][2][3]EOF
            ^
```

Si volvemos a leer, se leerá el EOF pero al no haber registros, el dato permanecerá con su valor anterior, dando la sensación de que el último dato se leyó por duplicado:

```
Dato: 3
[0][1][2][3]EOF
               ^
```

#### Solución.

Para evitar este problema, se puede aprovechar la [conversión implícita a booleano de los flujos de datos](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool), si una lectura no tiene lugar el valor del flujo será `false`:

```
// Solo se entra en el bucle si se lee algo:
while (Archivo.read((char *)(&elemento),sizeof(Lista))){
    cout << "Asignatura: " << elemento.Dato << endl;
    cout << "Cantidad de elementos: " << elemento.cantidad << endl;

    // Solo se avanza si se lee algo:
    if (Archivo2.read((char *)(&sub_elemento),sizeof(Sub_Lista)))
    {
        i = 0;
        while (i < elemento.cantidad ){ // 96 x TDA
            cout << "Nivel: " << sub_elemento.nivel << endl;
            cout << "TEL: " << sub_elemento.tel << endl;
            cout << "SCT: " << sub_elemento.sct << endl;
            cout << "Naturaleza: " << sub_elemento.naturaleza << endl;
            cout << endl;
            i++;
    }
}
```

#### Propuesta.

El código anterior soluciona el problema, pero no es la solución adecuada para C++ moderno. En su lugar deberías sobrecargar los operadores de extracción e inyección de datos:

```
std::istream operator>>(std::istream &i, Sub_Lista &sl) {
    return i.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&sl), sizeof(sl));
}

std::istream operator>>(std::istream &i, Lista &l) {
    return i.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&l), sizeof(l));
}

std::ostream operator<<(std::ostream &o, const Sub_Lista &sl) {
    return o << sl.sct << '\n'
             << sl.nivel << '\n'
             << sl.tel << '\n'
             << sl.naturaleza;
}

std::ostream operator<<(std::ostream &o, const Lista &l) {
    return o << l.Dato << '\n'
             << l.cantidad;
}
```

Con este código, tu función de lectura de datos podría quedar así:

```
void Lectura_archivo(){
    // Si "Elemento.txt" se puede abrir…
    if (std::ifstream Archivo{"Elemento.txt", ios::binary})
    {
        // Si "Sub_elementos.txt" se puede abrir…
        if (std::ifstream Archivo2{"Sub_elementos.txt", ios::binary})
        {
            Lista elemento{};
            // Mientras leamos elementos…
            while (Archivo >> elemento)
            {
                std::cout << "Elemento leido: " << elemento << '\n';

                Sub_Lista sub_elemento{};
                // Mientras leamos sub_elementos…
                while (Archivo2 >> sub_elemento)
                {
                    std::cout << "Subelemento leido: " << sub_elemento << '\n';
                }
            }
        }
        else
            std::cout << "No se pudo abrir Sub_elementos.txt\n";
    }
    else
        std::cout << "No se pudo abrir Elemento.txt\n";
}
```

Respecto a la propuesta, debo destacar:

- Usa las conversiones de tipo C++ (`xxxxx_cast<tipo>(expresión)`), evitando usar las de tipo C (`(tipo)expresión`), que son las que se deben usar.
- Usa la conversión implícita a booleano para comprobar que los archivos se abrieron.
- No llama a `ifstream::close` en la función de lectura, los archivos se cierran solos al salir de ámbito las variables `Archivo` y `Archivo2`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, espero mejorar con tus comentarios y algún día poder ayudar a la comunidad, perdón por mi mala programación de a poco mejoraré

Comment: Hola probando las funciones que me dejo se repiten todos los elementos,sera un error de mi compilador?, sobre el código propuesto me da un error de "-std = c++ 11" , compilo en `dev-C++ 5.11, perdón las molestias

Comment: @Trapss perdón por la tardanza, no vi tus comentarios. En mis pruebas no se repite ningún dato, debes haber hecho algo diferente, comparte tu código para que podamos averiguar que puede estar mal. Respecto al error `-std=C++11`, el compilador te está pidiendo que uses C++11 o superior, añade `-std=C++11` a los parámetros de compilación.