# fscanf y feof: comportamiento inesperado

Tags: c

Estoy tratando de almacenar un archivo `.txt` en variables tipo `char` en C, el problema es que el resultado al compilar me imprime dos veces la última línea y no entiendo la razón.

- En el archivo `.txt` tengo lo siguiente:

```
123.22.0.212 255.255.0.0
2.169.73.5 255.255.0.0
2.50.10.36 255.255.192.0
```

- Resultado al Compilar es el siguiente:

```
123.22.0.212 255.255.0.0
2.169.73.5 255.255.0.0
2.50.10.36 255.255.192.0
2.50.10.36 255.255.192.0
```

- Código en C:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE * archivo = fopen("direcciones.txt", "rb");    

    if(archivo == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error en la apertura del archivo");
        return 1;
    }

    /*leyendo caracter por caracter*/
    char ip[12];
    char mask[12];

    while( feof(archivo) == 0)
    {
        fscanf(archivo, "%s%s", &ip, &mask);
        printf("%s %s\n", ip, mask);
    }

    fclose(archivo);
    printf("\n\nSe ha leido el archivo correctamente...");

    return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Primero, lo que no preguntas pero está igualmente mal:

Tus datos de prueba son:

> 123.22.0.212 255.255.0.0
>   2.169.73.5 255.255.0.0
>   2.50.10.36 255.255.192.0

Y tus variables para almacenarlos

```
char ip[12];
char mask[12];
```

Sin embargo, según mis cuentas, `255.255.192.0` **tiene 13 caracteres**. Tus variables están mal dimensionadas. Y ya puestos, `255.255.255.255` necesitaría **16 bytes**. 15 para los caracteres en sí, y 1 mas para el `0` final.

Seguimos:

```
char ip[16];
char mask[16];
...
fscanf(archivo, "%s%s", &ip, &mask);
```

En C, **no existe** el concepto de *buffer* o *zona-de-memoria-continua*. Una formación o arreglo **no existe como tal**. A grandes rasgos, es un favor que te hace el compilador de reservarte un trozo de memoria ... **y te entrega un puntero a esa zona**.

En otras palabras: `ip` y `mask` **ya son punteros**. De hecho, si usas `&ip` o `&mask`, el compilador te mostrará un *bonito* aviso:

> warning: format `%s` expects argument of type `char *`, but argument has type `char (*)[12]`

Vale, ahora tu problema: Muy sencillo, `feof( )` comprueba el indicador *eof* del archivo, pero dicho indicador solo se establece **al realizar una operación**, nunca antes:

1. El `feof( )` comprueba que todo está bien.
2. Lees del archivo.
3. El `feof( )` comprueba que todo está bien.
4. Al estar ya al final del archivo, `fscanf( )` **no lee nada** (con lo que se mantiene lo último que hubieras leido. **Ahora** se establece el indicador `eof`.
5. El `feof( )` detecta el problema.

Tu código, corregido, quedaría así:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( ) {
  FILE * archivo = fopen( "direcciones.txt", "rb" );    

  if( archivo == NULL ) {
    perror( "Error en la apertura del archivo" );
    return 1;
  }

  char ip[16];
  char mask[16];

  while( 1 ) {
    fscanf( archivo, "%s%s", ip, mask );

    if( feof( archivo ) != 0 ) {
      break;
    }

    printf( "%s %s\n", ip, mask );
  }

  fclose( archivo );
  printf( "\nSe ha leido el archivo correctamente...\n" );

  return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta. [Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/320974/2742) el mismo problema versión [tag:c++].

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Estoy `99.99%` seguro de que ya hay varias sobre esto ... pero no las encontraba, y tenía un ratito muerto que aprovechar. El buscador interno del sitio deja bastante que desear :-(

Comment: No he puesto el comentario para criticar tu respuesta si no para complementarla, aunque si quieres fustigarte: siéntete libre de hacerlo.

Comment: No me he explicado. Lo que quiero decir es que la pregunta ya se ha echo varias veces y habría que marcarla como duplicada ... pero que tardaba mas en buscar una anterior que en responderla. Gracias por el *piropo* en todo caso :-)

Comment: @Trauma que tal? Volví a ejecutar tu código y ahora el problema es que no me lee la ultima linea, no se porque

Comment: Hola @Alvarez. He vuelto a probarlo, y se ejecuta correctamente para tus datos de prueba. ¿ Puede ser que tengas algún caracter *extraño* en tu archivo a leer ?