# Lectura de Archivos Duplica ultimo Valor?

Tags: c++, archivo

## Hola me podrian apoyar con la lectura de este archivo#

Me podrían apoyar estoy intentando abrir un archivo separado por comas el cual
viene  asi solo deseo tomar el primer valor y el ultimo de cada fila, he intentado
pero no logro encontrar el fallo...

```
>513645965,02-09-17,1188.99  
>288608909,29-07-17,1251.86  
>481274889,05-12-17,1371.49  
pero mi programa al abrirlo y mostrar los datos me muestra:  
>513645965 1188.99  
>288608909 1251.86  
>481274889 1371.49  
>1371.49  
Duplicando el ultimo dato...



#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    
        ifstream ip;
        string dato1;
        string dato2;
        string dato3;
    
        cout << "No" << "\tCANT" << endl;
        ip.open("c.csv", ios::in);
        while (ip.good()) {
    
                getline(ip, dato1, ',');
                getline(ip, dato2, ',');
                getline(ip, dato3, '\n');
                cout << dato1;
                cout << " "<<dato3 << endl;
    }
        ip.close();
        return 0;
    
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No estoy seguro de porqué el error ya que esa forma de abrir el archivo no la conocía, yo supongo que al usar `while (ip.good())` es similar a leer por EOF, i.e. `while (!ip.eof())` que no es la forma correcta de leer un archivo ya que se leería un dato de más (ver este [hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/320974/154404)), tal vez esto nos los pueda desmentir o confirmar alguien más experto.

En fin, creo que la forma más correcta de leer un archivo se hace aprovechando la conversión implícita a booleano de los flujos de datos, de esta manera podemos abrir el archivo usando un condicional y olvidándonos del uso de `ip.open` y de `ip.close` ya que estos también se harán implícitamente.

Considerando todo lo señalado, la lectura del archivo podría hacerse así:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::string dato1;
    std::string dato2;
    std::string dato3;
    std::cout << "No" << "\tCANT" << std::endl;

    //abriendo el archivo
    if (std::ifstream file{ "c.csv" })
    {
        std::string line;
        while (getline(file, line)) {
            std::stringstream strstr(line);

            //obteniendo e imprimiendo primer valor
            getline(strstr, dato1, ',');
            std::cout << dato1;

            //obteniendo segundo valor sin imprimir
            getline(strstr, dato2, ',');

            //obteniendo e imprimiendo tercer valor
            getline(strstr, dato3, ',');
            std::cout << " " << dato3 << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```